# app engine: string to datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

i have string

```
date = "11/28/2009"
hour = "23"
minutes = "59"
seconds = "00"
```

how can i convert to datetime object and store it in datastore?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I apologize if this isn't what you want, but at least for the first part of the question you could probably do it like so?

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(date + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 28, 23, 59)
```

Comment: thx!! this is the correct answer. store in datastore will be sth like:
record = Model()
record.date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
record.put()